# IE keeps holding mouse/touch down when releasing outside of Iframe window

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I've been looking for an answer for days, but to no avail. I'm making this Cordova app where in IE I need to run all unsafe webcontent in an IFrame. So far everything is going well, but I am running into a problem with Internet Explorer 11 to 9 and Window Phone 8.1 IE. in Firefox and Chrome is works fine.

When I press the left-mouse down inside the IFrame and drag it outside the IFrame and release, I can move my mouse inside the IFrame again and it still thinks that my left-mouse button is pressed down. This also happends when using touch controls and makes the problem so much worse.

I have this fiddle example that shows the problem. Try dragging the map outside of the Fiddle IFrame release and move back to the map to confirm that mouse/touch is still down.
http://jsfiddle.net/pkbkn0me/3/

Thanks in advance. I'm having a hard time debugging this issue but i suspect that it is some mouse/touch event that is not being triggered.

```
<div id="mapdisplay" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; background: grey" />

<script>

$(function() {
/**
* Moves the map to display over Berlin
*
* @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
*/



function moveMapToBerlin(map) {
    map.setCenter({ lat: 52.5159, lng: 13.3777 });
    map.setZoom(14);
}

/**
* Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
*/

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform

var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    app_id: '32pgIHkvuyWtWbBM7LhF',
    app_code: 'fpwF_cWgzvckmNL12RchNg',
    useCIT: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map  - not specificing a location will give a whole world view.

var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapdisplay'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map);

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
moveMapToBerlin(map);

});

<script/>
```

Comment: I used Internet Explorer 11 (11.0.9600.17501) to test, but it worked normally.

Comment: Weird I use IE 11 (11.0.9600.17631) and it also happends when I emulate IE 10.
Wait did you drag it all the way outside of the Fiddle result window?

Comment: Nope, just to the right of the map.

Comment: I just tried it on another computer and the problem is also there. To test this problem you need to drag it outside of the Fiddle result window as the result window itself is a IFrame.